# How to delete lubuntu from Windows 10 Dual Boot [Cannot see lubuntu partition]

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, lubuntu

Two weeks ago i installed Lubuntu for test purpose as dual boot. It installed GRUB as boot loader, but now i want to remove lubuntu from my disk, but i cannot find the linux partition. This is what i see:

[Only C:/ partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltxDZ.png)

So now i don't know how to delete lubuntu

Update:

This is what i have using gparted:

[image: gparted]

Comment: Windows does not recognize Ubuntu (Lubuntu) partitions. So Windows can't show you what it can't see. Use the live installation USB and try Lubuntu option to see the Lubuntu partition.

Comment: **As above but what you're showing only has Windows partitions**. Possibly you installed Lubuntu in an external drive that wasn't connected when you took that screeshot? If not how exactly did you install Lubuntu?

Comment: I installed Lubuntu in a **USB** and installed it. I selected **"Install Lubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager"** instead of custom install. If it doesn't show Lubuntu partition, what can i do so i can delete it?

Comment: Make sure Lubuntu is not involved in the booting of your system, if it is and you remove it, you'll find you've lost access to boot into your windows as well.  You didn't give release details on Lubuntu so tools differ, but I'd be using windows tools myself (given that's what you're keeping, but windows is off-topic here)

Comment: *I installed Lubuntu in a USB and installed it* is actually meaningless, everybody does that. *How* was it installed is what I asked and the "install alongside" doesn't do it either. But you must have been informed where Lubuntu would have been installed. Did you had an additional (external) drive during installation that wasn't connected when you took that screenshot? Again, there Windows partitions ONLY. Lubuntu was never installed in the drive you're showing us, period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 Ways:

1. You boot from a live cd/usb, on your desk you search the programm **gparted** and open it, you should see something like this: [image]
   here you see many partitions I don't know how you setup your Lubuntu, but in most cases it is enough to delete the **ext4** partition and the **linux-swap**. After that you can resize to maximum your **Windows(NTFS)** partiton.

Image source: https://superuser.com/questions/1474987/how-do-i-fix-the-partitions-and-dual-boot-with-windows-10-ubuntu-19-04

2. in your windows you should have a partition manager, there you delete all partitions who aren't needed. This way may unnecessary complicated.

In your explorer Linux aren't showed because of the missing ext driver. You could say Windows won't support Linux.

Comment: So what are the steps should i follow to completely delete Lubuntu?

Comment: I updated my answer is it now clearer?

Comment: @thestuckboy Please do as instructed in #1 then edit your question and add a screenshot of Gparted. And again, check for other drives. This whole thing without an additional drive that you aren't showing being involved in the process is totally nonsensical.

Comment: @ChanganAuto i edited the question

Comment: @thestuckboy Now it makes sense although it doesn't match with the Windows screenshot. sda5 and sda6 are logical partitions inside the extended sd4 (the logical one need to be deleted before the extended). Please follow the instructions in the link of the first comment under the question carefully. **Because you have a Legacy/BIOS installation it's not a simple matter of deleting partitions, you must have the Windows installation USB and reinstall the Windows bootloader.**

Comment: So this is the first thing i should do:

1.-Delete extended sda4 partition
2.-Delete sda5 and sda6 partition

am i wrong?
what is suppose to happen if i delete those partitions?

Comment: @thestuckboy after that you successfully remove Lubuntu from your disk

Comment: Now i got two new questions:

1-After i delete Lubuntu, do i still have the grub?
2-If yes, i suppose i can still load Windows...?
3-If i want to delete GRUB from my PC, do i have to use a Windows 10 iso to recover the windows boot?

Comment: Yes, you still have Grub, cause Grub was installed in MBR, you need to overwrite your MBR with the Windows iso, as you say.

Comment: So what if i just want to delete lubuntu, and have another Ubuntu based distro like Linux Mint? Sorry for making so many questions the things is i'm really noob at this:(

Comment: Then you must delete nothing manually, you boot up mint run the installer and use /dev/sda5 as / (this step deletes Lubuntu and installs mint)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123314/discussion-between-thestuckboy-and-lucki1000).